# maccatalyst validation upload fail, no records found

Tags: xcode, macos, bundle-identifier, mac-catalyst

I made an app which is on the App Store for iOS.

In Xcode, I selected support for MacOS in target > deployment info.

In appconnect > my apps, there is a macOS version below the iOS version.

I have archived with My Mac scheme but when I validate it, there is an error message to say:

No suitable Application records were found.  Verify your bundle Identifier maccatalyst........  is correct.

My bundle ID is a match without the maccatalyst.com prefix.

I have tried changing the bundle ID to the required prefix before archiving but the result is the same.  If Appconnect has the macOS version, why can't the validation see it?

I can't seem to find a solution to get this.[image: Appstore MacOS Catalyst]

[image: Maccatalyst no application records found]

Answer (score 1):

Older xcode (pre 14) add the maccatalyst to the id. To fix this, go to your 'Build Settings', change the 'Derive Mac Catalyst Product Bundle Identifier' to 'No'.

https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev07ed024a6